# str_replace a CSS property based upon a CSS comment

Tags: php, javascript, css, ajax, str-replace

I'm building a "theme builder" that will dynamically edit a CSS file on-the-fly. I figured using PHP would be the easiest option (willing to consider alternative methods).

My CSS file contains comments after each property like so:

```
html,body {
    background: #fff url(../images/bg.jpg) repeat-x; /*{bgColor}*/ 
    color: #fff; /*{textColor}*/ 
}
```

Is it possible to use a replace function that searches for that comment and replaces only the code before it? The user may want to go back once they've finished building the theme and change something again, so the comment must remain at all times.

Thanks

Comment: Into which concrete problem did you run? Just replace with the comment again at the end of the line and it should be fine.

Comment: Ah I see. In which case, how would I search for the comment, and then replace the entire line?

Comment: What is the expected output? The first line is ambiguous, since the `bgColor` property translates to `background-color`.

Comment: Why not store the theme as a template with php variables for the substitution points, and then set the variables and render the output when needed?

Comment: the theme is being shown in an iframe on a different page so the CSS file needs to be valid. That is why I want the CSS comments after the property. The same properties within the CSS might be edited more than once as well, so the comment must remain at all times so the php replace function has something to find if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you generating the CSS on page load, or are you regenerating a CSS file when the theme gets added?

If you generate the CSS on edit of the theme, you could do this;

`/*bodybg*/ background: #fff url(../images/bg.jpg) repeat-x; /*/bodybg*/`

You could do something like:

```
$shortCode = bodybg
$cssContents = preg_replace("/(\/\*".$shortCode."\*\/).*?(\/\*\/".$shortCode."\*\/)/i",
                            "\\1 background: #F00; \\2", 
                            $cssContents);
```

If you generate the CSS on page load, you could do this:

`background: {{bodyBgColor}} url(../images/bg.jpg) repeat-x;`

`$cssContents = str_replace("{{bodyBgColor}}", $color, $cssContents);`

Comment: I have a page with a form and an iframe. The iframe is loading a preview of the theme. When the user updates the form (eg - changes the background color field) I want it to then perform the PHP replace function on the CSS file. As that field may possibly be edited multiples times though, the CSS comment must remain so that it can be referenced each time by the replace function. Not sure this makes sense but hopefully it does.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you follow the pattern that you have the `varname` at the end of the line and that each line contains a CSS `property : value` only, you can do it with a regular expression based search and replace.

If you want to do so, take care that the new value does not contain anything newline-ish in the PCRE sense: `\r\n|\n|\x0b|\f|\r|\x85` (non UTF-8 mode). If you don't, this will break your parser!

To do so, you can create a mask for the pattern so you can then insert the varname later on easily, I normally use [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) for that:

```
$patternMask = 
'~
   ^ # start of line

    (\s*[a-z]+:\s*)
    # Group 1: 
    #   whitespace (indentation)
    #   + CSS property and ":"
    #   + optional whitespace

    (.*?) # Group 2: CSS value (to replace)

    (\s*/\*\{%s\}\*/\s*)
    # Group 3: 
    #   whitespace (after value and before variable)
    #   + variable comment, %%s is placeholder for it\'s name

   $ # end of line

   # Pattern Modifiers:
   #   m: ^ & $ match begin/end of each line
   #   x: ignore spaces in pattern and allow comments (#)
  ~mx'
;
```

This is the regex pattern with comments, made possible with the `x`-modifier. Just so it's easier for you to understand.

An important point is the `m`-modifier for multi-line mode. The pattern should work on each line, so it's enclosed into `^` (Begin) and `$` (End), which will match the begin and end of a line in multi-line mode.

When you do the replace operation, group 2 will be replaced, group 1 and 3 will be preserved. That done, the result will still contain the variable name.

The actual regex pattern is then build with this mask by adding a properly quoted variable name into it using `sprintf` and [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg_quote):

```
$varName = 'bgColor';
$value = '#f00 url(../images/bg-reg.jpg) repeat-x;';

# create regex pattern based on varname
$pattern =  sprintf($patternMask, preg_quote($varName, $patternMask[0]));
```

`$patternMask[0]` is `~` so if your variable name would contain `~` it would be properly escaped automatically.

The search pattern is now complete. What's left is the replacement. As the variable name, the replacement string also needs escaping to not break it regex-wise (syntax error). Additionally as stated earlier, the overall process needs to take care to preserve the new string to be a single line, otherwise doing the replace operation next time would break it. So to prevent that, any newline character will be replace with a single space in `$value` to prevent that:

```
# replace characters that will break the pattern with space
$valueFiltered = str_replace(explode('|', "\r\n|\n|\x0b|\f|\r|\x85"), ' ', $value);
```

Then the special characters `\` and `$` will be quoted so they won't interfere with the replacement pattern and the replacement string is build. this is done with the [`addcslashes`](http://php.net/addcslashes) function:

```
# escape $ characters as they have a special meaning in the replace string 
$valueEscaped = addcslashes($valueFiltered, '\$');
$replace = sprintf('${1}%s$3', $valueEscaped);
```

The only thing left is to run the replacement operation, so giving it ssome CSS upfront:

```
$css = <<<CSS
html,body {
    background: #fff url(../images/bg.jpg) repeat-x; /*{bgColor}*/ 
    color: #fff; /*{textColor}*/ 
}
CSS;
```

and run the replace with [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
$newCss = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $css);
```

This is the whole thing already. From the original CSS:

```
html,body {
    background: #fff url(../images/bg.jpg) repeat-x; /*{bgColor}*/ 
    color: #fff; /*{textColor}*/ 
}
```

To the outcome CSS:

```
html,body {
    background: #f00 url(../images/bg-reg.jpg) repeat-x; /*{bgColor}*/ 
    color: #fff; /*{textColor}*/ 
}
```

If you make use of `preg_replace`'s `&$count` parameter you can check if the variable was part of the string:

```
$newCss = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $css, -1, $count);
```

`$count` is 1 in the example given.

If you like to replace multiple values at once, you can use arrays as `$pattern` and `$replace` in case it's helpful. `$count` will still be an integer, so it might be of limited use.

The whole code at a glance:

```
$css = <<<CSS
html,body {
    background: #fff url(../images/bg.jpg) repeat-x; /*{bgColor}*/ 
    color: #fff; /*{textColor}*/ 
}
CSS;


$patternMask = 
'~
   ^ # start of line

    (\s*[a-z]+:\s*)
    # Group 1: 
    #   whitespace (indentation)
    #   + CSS property and ":"
    #   + optional whitespace

    (.*?) # Group 2: CSS value (to replace)

    (\s*/\*\{%s\}\*/\s*)
    # Group 3: 
    #   whitespace (after value and before variable)
    #   + variable comment, %%s is placeholder for it\'s name

   $ # end of line

   # Pattern Modifiers:
   #   m: ^ & $ match begin/end of each line
   #   x: ignore spaces in pattern and allow comments (#)
  ~mx'
;

$varName = 'bgColor';
$value = '#f00 url(../images/bg-reg.jpg) repeat-x;';

# create regex pattern based on varname
$pattern =  sprintf($patternMask, preg_quote($varName, $patternMask[0]));

# replace characters that will break the pattern with space
$valueFiltered = str_replace(explode('|', "\r\n|\n|\x0b|\f|\r|\x85"), ' ', $value);

# escape $ characters as they have a special meaning in the replace string 
$valueEscaped = addcslashes($valueFiltered, '\$');

$replace = sprintf('${1}%s$3', $valueEscaped);

$newCss = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $css);

echo $newCss;
```

Answer (score 1):

Did something very similar to this a few years back, but how I did it was to have a session variable with that would be read within the CSS (or rather PHP) file when loaded.

So... if you create a php file that will act as your CSS file and copy this into it...

```
header("Content-type: text/css");
// setup replacement variables here...
// NOTE: if using the session object to start the session
// as the stylesheet is running in a seperate process as the rest of the site...

$textColor = "#ff0000";     // This is a variable that will appear in the CSS 

$fHandle = @fopen("site.css", "r");   // Change this to your CSS file...
if ($fHandle) {
    while (($line = fgets($fHandle, 4096)) !== false) {
        $variable = getTextBetween($line,"/*{","}*/");
        if ($variable != ""){
            if (isSet($$variable)){
                // we have that variable... now what to actually do with it...
                // what we are going to do is rebuild the line...
                $attribute = getTextBetween($line,0,":");
                // and thats it really...
                echo($attribute.":".$$variable.";".chr(10));   // NOTE: Double $$ to access the string as a variable :)
            } else {
                // that variable does not exist. Just output the line
                echo $line;
            }
        } else {
            // there is no variable just output the line
            echo $line;
        }
    }
    fclose($fHandle);
}

function getTextBetween($string_in,$start_in,$end_in){
    $_start = 0;
    $_end = 0;
    // calculate the start and the end points.
    if (is_string($start_in)){
        $_start = strpos($string_in,$start_in);
        if ($_start === false){
            $_start = 0;
        } else {
            $_start += strlen($start_in);
        }
    } else if (is_numeric($start_in)){
        $_start = $start_in;
    }

    if (is_string($end_in)){
        $_end = strpos($string_in,$end_in,$_start);
        if ($_end === false) $_end = 0;
    } else if (is_numeric($end_in)){
        $_end = $end_in;
    }

    $_return = substr($string_in,$_start,($_end-$_start));

    return trim($_return);
}
```

Then include the file in the same way as a normal stylesheet...

And if you setup all your variables the same name as in your example... it will work how you want it to work without you having to change any code to suit other ways of doing things :)

If you need any help with it, please let me know :)

Good luck :)

Love to all :)

Comment: In that case I'd rather just write the CSS file as a PHP file using echo where user variables should be output. Same way as with regular HTML, just with a different content-type :)

Comment: That's very true... instead of adding small functionality to adjust the already written CSS file that has comments... could just rewrite the CSS file as a PHP file, change the content-type and where you have items that require change instead of the comments have the variables... Adding in an echo based on if the variable exists or not... like... echo(isSet($textColor) ? $textColor : "#fff;"); Good Point Svish :)